# Good OOP design of a Linear Solver in Fortran

Tags: oop, fortran

I am programming a program in OOP Fortran for the solution of linear systems *A x* = *b*.

The linear solver will require the use of the matrix-vector operation, thus I built a type containing the matrix (only a single number in the following example) and the matrix-vector multiplication procedure.

```
module Matrices
  implicit none
  private
  type, public :: matrix
     real*8 :: coeff
   contains
     procedure, public, pass :: init
     procedure, public, pass :: mxv => multiplication
  end type matrix
contains
  subroutine init(this,coeff)
    implicit none
    class(matrix), intent(inout) :: this
    real*8,        intent(in   ) :: coeff
    this%coeff=coeff
  end subroutine init

  subroutine multiplication(this,x,y)
    implicit none
    class(matrix), intent(in ) :: this
    real*8,        intent(in ) :: x
    real*8,        intent(out) :: y
    y=this%coeff*x
  end subroutine multiplication
end module Matrices
```

I built also a second  type describing a composed matrix *M* = *A* + *h B* with *A*, *B* of type matrix and *h* a real number.

```
module ComposedMatrices
  use Matrices
  implicit none

  private
  type, public :: cmatrix
     type(matrix) :: m1,m2
     real*8 :: h
   contains
     procedure, public, pass :: init
     procedure, public, pass :: mxv => multiplication
  end type cmatrix
contains
  subroutine init(this,m1,m2,h)
    implicit none
    class(cmatrix), intent(inout) :: this
    type(matrix),   intent(in   ) :: m1,m2
    real*8,         intent(in   ) :: h
    this%m1=m1
    this%m2=m2
    this%h=h
  end subroutine init

  subroutine multiplication(this,x,y)
    implicit none
    class(cmatrix), intent(inout) :: this
    real*8,        intent(in   ) :: x
    real*8,        intent(out  ) :: y
    ! local
    real*8 :: temp

    call this%m1%mxv(x,y)
    call this%m2%mxv(x,temp)
    y=y+this%h*temp
  end subroutine multiplication
end module ComposedMatrices
```

Then I build the module solver where the matrix-vector multiplication is called (subroutine powers gives an example of that). I used the unlimited polymorphism + select type .

```
module Solver
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine powers(general_matrix,npower,x,y)
    use Matrices
    use ComposedMatrices
    class(*), intent(in)  :: general_matrix
    integer,  intent(in ) :: npower
    real*8,   intent(in ) :: x
    real*8,   intent(out) :: y 
    !local
    integer :: i
    real*8 :: temp

    temp=x
    do i=1,npower
       select type(general_matrix)
       type is (matrix)
          call general_matrix%mxv(temp,y)
       type is (cmatrix)
          call general_matrix%mxv(temp,y)
       end select
       temp=y
    end do

  end subroutine powers
end module Solver
program test
use Matrices
use ComposedMatrices
use Solver
```

The example program below works with no problem

```
type(matrix) :: m1,m2
type(cmatrix) :: m3
integer :: npowers=2
real*8 :: x=2.0d0
real*8 :: y
real*8 :: h=1.0d0

call m1%init(1.0d0)
call m2%init(2.0d0)
call m3%init(m1,m2,h)

call powers(m1,npowers,x,y)
write(*,*) y

call powers(m2,npowers,x,y)
write(*,*) y

call powers(m3,npowers,x,y)
write(*,*) y
end program
```

**My question is**: there is any way to design the module `Solver` such that I do not have to tell with `select type` how to use the matrix vector-multiplication? In other words, is it possible to build the procedure `powers` so the variable `general_matrix` will be of any type with matrix-vector multiplication procedure?

I ask this question because I would like to "leave clear" the code in the Solver Module, something like:

```
    temp=x
    do i=1,npower
       call general_matrix%mxv(temp,y)
       temp=y
    end do
```

Comment: Welcome. Please tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Also please take the welcome [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Why have you done things the way you have?  Why isn't cmatrix an extension of matrix?  What is the point of the init binding being a binding?  Avoid `real*8` - it isn't Fortran.

Comment: If a declare the type cmatrix as an extension of the type matrix, how do I pass the two matrices m1 and  m2( that compose the cmatrix type) ,into the init procedure of type cmatrix?

Comment: I'd proceed no further without careful study of *Scientific Software Design* by Damian Rouson *et al*.

Comment: What is the point of the init binding being a binding?  If it is trying to be some sort of constructor, just write it as a stand-along subroutine.  Constructors are inherently type specific, there is no point to them being type bound.

Comment: Yes, the init procedure should play tthe ruel of a constructor.

Comment: Yes, the init procedure should play the rule of a constructor.
Thanks for the suggestion of  the book 'Scientific Software Design'.